# How to modify request.args before route in flask

Tags: flask

My encrypted url is like:

> http://host/interface/register?b0ba06b19a18a68394eb4a4eb6e7c2a2eaa0c25f0d42106efa05e382711bd5a83a49fe32b295057d4e6ea642563f9643a6bfa2c72f8333df865b47462c096980d5b4314f2d80dda11b850e5bc54899e06f7ac53856db88705b1cf9e087a0e11f5c0f1e62cc1e27285b1cf9e087a0e11fdba9c24d029d99d1e68c943145205c88b430ca6865528840065032b92f6b9d9eb5afc5fd5cb28e9aefec62361801f617

I want to use the decoded args in the route:

```
@app.route('/interface/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def interface_register():
  args = request.args.to_dict()
  id = args.get('id', "")
  name = args.get('name', "")
  ...
```

So I try to modify args in app.before_request:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # decode and modify request.args
```

Because the request.args is read only, it's not success, how to decode and modify the raw request.args before call `request.args.to_dict()?`

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

def your_decode(qs):
  # implement your decryption here
  return qs

url = 'http://blah/?id=1&y=[1,2]&blah=dd' # >> replace with request.url
qs = urlparse(url).query
decoded_qs = your_decode(qs)
o = parse_qs(decoded_qs)
print(o)
```

prints

```
{'blah': ['dd'], 'id': ['1'], 'y': ['[1,2]']}
```

Comment: sorry for my description is ambiguous, I just want to know where to place decryption code, and how to write back to the read only request.url or replace the older request by a new one.